# Use of default constructor, which does not provide a comment

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I am trying to run a maven javadoc command on SpringB oot @Configuration classes without warnings.

Currently, I have a very straightforward Spring Boot configuration class as follows:

```
/**
 * This is Some Configuration. There is ome meaningful doc here.
 */
@Configuration
public class SomeConfiguration {

    @Value("${my.host}")
    private String host;

    /**
     * span exporter.
     * This is used to send traces to the host.
     * Some more meaningful doc here.
     *
     * @return the span exporter
     */
    @Bean
    public SpanExporter spanExporter() {
        return OtlpGrpcSpanExporter.builder().setEndpoint(host).build();
    }

}
```

and in my pom, to generate Javadoc, I have this:

```xml
<reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target/javadoc</outputDirectory>
                    <reportOutputDirectory>target/javadoc</reportOutputDirectory>
                    <javadocExecutable>${java.home}/bin/javadoc</javadocExecutable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

When running this command `mvn clean install site -U javadoc:javadoc` I am always getting:

```
[WARNING] C:\Users\me\SomeConfiguration.java:13: warning: use of default constructor, which does not provide a comment
[WARNING] public class SomeConfiguration{
[WARNING] ^
```

How to fix this without bringing an entire constructor such as this below to the mist?

```
public class SomeConfiguration {
    
    private String host;

    public SomeConfiguration(@Value("${my.host}") String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try explicitly adding the default constructor, `public SomeConfiguration() { }` (leaving the rest of your code as shown in the first example)? What happened?